# How to disable mouse cursor change on cefSharp v117.2.40?

Tags: chromium, cefsharp

I am using cefSharp v117.2.40 and looking at some examples to control mouse cursor changes.

To handle mouse cursor changes, cefSharp v51.0.0.0 uses the MouseCursorChangeDisabled method as follows:

IBrowserHost browserHost = browser.GetBrowser().GetHost();
browserHost.MouseCursorChangeDisabled = true;

But I don't find any examples about cefSharp v117.2.40!
If anyone knows how to deal with cefSharp v117.2.40, please reply.

For reference, according to the following post, MouseCursorChangeDisabled has been removed.
https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3275

Comment: The property was removed as per the `GitHub` issue. If you read the issue in full you'll see that the same functionality can be achieved via `OnCursorChange`.

Comment: @amaitland, You are insincere in answering!

I registered a question because there was no specific example of how to handle OnCursorChange in the content of the github post.

I hope you can help me if you know anything about this.

Comment: How to implement IDisplayHandler OnCursorChange of ChromiumWebBrowser on cefSharp v117.2.40?

If anyone knows how to do, please reply!

Comment: I was simply providing a hint to get your moving on your own, you'll note that I only posted a comment, not an answer. There are examples of using a `DisplayHandler` within the project source. Create a class that inherits from `CefSharp.Handler.DisplayHandler`, override the method you require, assistance the instance to the `ChromiumWebBrowser.DisplayHandler` property.